# How To Get Selenium Grid 2 Running 1 Test In Multiple Browsers In Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, cross-browser, nunit, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using the following technologies:

- Selenium Webdriver 2.0 in .net
- Selenium Grid 2
- SpecFlow
- Ms Visual Studio
- Resharper

My problem is that, how do I get the test to run in different browsers like both Firefox and Internet Explorer in parallel once I run the test.

At the moment it only runs the test once on the default browser and ignore the other browser I passed in the json file.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should be more keen on how the Node is registered.

To start a Node (use the following command)

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Incase if u had tried to start a node with browsers as well (check the following command)

```
-browser maxInstances=5
```

maxInstances --> Signify the Max sessions on a single node, irrespective of Browser

Please specify capabilities in your test case such that it invokes particular browser (IE,FF,Chrome) parallely to avoid default one.